# browsing through many paths for many files

Tags: bash, mapping

I am currently working on a small bash script that reads source C files and then finds corresponding include files.

Now I have to choose between two models of finding a mapping M: filename -> {include file paths }. What I have are two arrays - one with found include filenames and another containing possible paths. The options are :

a) look for each file in one path, then proceed to another path;

b) look through a list of paths to find one file, then proceed to another file.

My question is - what will be faster? There is equal number of iterations in each of the choices, but maybe some of the commands are more time-consuming? I personally prefer option a).

Thanks for any help and sorry if this was a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be the same amount of iterations only if you coded it badly, not using the `continue` keyword once a match is found (don't forget it can take a number as an argument to affect outer loops too).

I would iterate through all the include files and look into the paths with some ordering - `<system>` includes should search system include paths first for quicker results, while the same holds true for `"local"` includes. It would be unwise to discard this information while parsing.

However, I think you can do better by just running `find -type f` on all the include paths and storing the result in a temporary file or a variable. Then you would just `grep` (or any equivalent) it for the includes themselves. This way you save some I/O, since half of it is read in one go and only once.

Comment: Thank you for your comment,lynxlynxlynx, it helped a lot. I will try to implement it the way you advised =)

Answer (score 1):

What you should do depends on your goal, which I don't quite understand.  You probably should use makedepend, as mentioned in an earlier answer, if you are creating `make` files.

If instead you want to find out if there are multiple versions of header files on your system, consider using the `locate` command.  For example, on my ubuntu 12.04 linux system, the following command takes about a second to complete, and produces the output shown below the command.

```
  $ locate stdio.h | grep usr/include
  /usr/include/stdio.h
  /usr/include/c++/4.6/tr1/stdio.h
  /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstdio.h
  /usr/include/sharutils/stdio.h
  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h
```

If you have a list of library paths on separate lines of file pqr, and a list of header files in file xyz, you can use a command like

```
  locate / | grep -f xyz | grep -f pqr
```

(Note, `-F` could be used along with `-f`, if you like.) With two lines (`stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`) in `xyz` and two lines (`/usr/include/` and `/usr/lib/`) in `pqr`, the command takes .7 seconds on my system, to produce the output

```
  /usr/include/stdio.h
  /usr/include/stdlib.h
  /usr/include/c++/4.6/tr1/stdio.h
  /usr/include/c++/4.6/tr1/stdlib.h
  /usr/include/freetype2/freetype/config/ftstdlib.h
  /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gstdio.h
  /usr/include/sharutils/stdio.h
  /usr/include/sharutils/stdlib.h
  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio.h
  /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdlib.h
  /usr/lib/perl/5.14.2/CORE/nostdio.h
  /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdio.h
  /usr/lib/syslinux/com32/include/stdlib.h
```

Note, on a typical linux system, the file name database updates once a day.  That probably won't be a problem when looking for system header files.  For more-transient files, you might need to say `sudo updatedb` before using `locate`, and that will add a few seconds to a few minutes to the overall time.

Comment: Thank you very much, jwpat7 , this was very useful information. My goal was indeed to find multiple versions of header files and then print the paths to stdout, not to create makefiles. However, the problem is that I do not know if this filename database exists on every linux system... For testing my program I use mac OS X, not linux. I tried to use locate, but was asked for administrator password. I wonder if the same thing may happen when using this script on other systems where I don't have administrator rights.

Comment: locate has been a part of all the linux distributions I've used since slackware 0.98, except for live-CD versions, and available to ordinary users.  The updatedb command typically requires admin privileges, however.  Also, [google for mac os x locate database update](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=mac+os+x+locate+database+update&oq=mac+OS+X+locate&gs_l=hp.1.1.0l4.943.4898.0.7121.2.2.0.0.0.0.165.311.0j2.2.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.aX3F5_RK1Hk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=96a2ca9e4750509&bpcl=35277026&biw=923&bih=579) has a lot of links about locate on OS X.

Comment: OK, I already did, thanks. The aim is to make the program universal for linux, so maybe to avoid errors I'll somehow (yes, I am new to bash - only 3 weeks =) ) use if-clauses to check if it works. But if you say that locate MUST be part of all current linux distributions, then these errors are unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

To find your include files, a dedicated solution would be [makedepend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makedepend), in particular if you are using makefiles anyway.